# Setting a boost::variant that contains pointers, inside of a std::vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I have a std::vector of type boost::variant which contains pointers to standard built-in types.

In code

```
std::vector<boost::variant<int *, double *> > bv;
bv.resize(2);
int n = 42;
bv[0] = &n;
double d = 102.4;
bv[1] = &d;
```

This works well, and I can access the values in the vector by using `boost::get<int *>` or `boost::get<double *>`.

However, I was wondering if I could set the value of an element in the vector directly, instead of pointing it to a reference. In other words, I would like to do something like this

```
*bv[0] = 42;
*bv[1] = 102.4;
```

but this doesn't compile. Does anyone have advice on how to go about this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Apparently, I don't have enough points to answer my own question, so figured I'd put my solution in the original question instead. Hope this helps someone who stumbles across this page.

I figured I'd answer my own question, in case it helps someone. I wrote a visitor class, that modifies what the pointer in the variant refers to. Here's the code for the visitor class (of course, this can be made a templated class).

```
class specific_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    explicit specific_visitor(int i) : i_num(i) { }
    explicit specific_visitor(double d) : d_num(d) { }

    void operator()(int * i) const
    {
        *i = i_num;
    }

    void operator()(double * d) const
    {
    *d = d_num;
    }
private:
    int i_num;
    double d_num;
};
```

In order to use it for the vector of variants in the original question, here's the code:

```
int i_num = 34;
boost::apply_visitor(specific_visitor(i_num), bv[0]);
double d_num = 9.81;
boost::apply_visitor(specific_visitor(d_num), bv[1]);
```

Comment: Why use pointers here in the first place?

Comment: Well, I am trying to integrate boost::variant into a larger program, and that, unfortunately, is the only realistic option I have at this point.

Comment: @endbegin: That doesn't make sense to me. Why `std::vector<boost::variant<int, double> >` make it unrealistic?

Comment: @KennyTM, the way the program is set up, what is stored in the vector is a collection of pointers which point to "other things". So when I update the pointer's value in the variant/vector, the "other things" that are pointed to, also see the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need pointers, then
the answer is no, you can't,
because - most probably - there is no feasible way
to allocate and later free the needed memory.

If you need to allocate the memory for (almost?) all
the values, then `boost::variant<int, double>` is
a way to go.

If you need to store pointers to (almost?) all of
the values and allocate memory for a minority of them,
then you need a more complex solution (anyway).

Comment: I guess I just need a way to set the values the pointers in the variant are pointing to. For instance, the int * in the variant is pointing to a location containing an integer, and there are other parts of the program pointing to the location. So in the variant, if I can change the contents of that location, then I'd be alright.

Comment: What part of code will allocate memory for that values?
Where - heap, stack, static data?
What part of code is going too free it later?

It seems to me that you need `boost::variant<int, double>` to allocate the space for you, then you can set the values and take their addresses to get the pointers you need to the other parts of the program.

Comment: BTW, is there a specific reason not to store ints in the double type - the 8-byte double can perfectly store ints at least up to magnitude of 10^15 (I think 52 bits).

Comment: @endbegin, note that int `n = 42; bv[0] = &n;` is fundamentally different than `*bv[0] = 42`; or `* boost::get<int *>(bv[0]) = 42` - the first would modify the element of the vector (a pointer), the second woud modify the memory location referenced by the pointer.

Comment: I can't store everything in a double type, because I might have to add support for complex<double> or other custom types in the future. I also want a higher-level solution, so it is easier for someone coming in to be able to maintain the code easily.